# Django 1.11 - Webpack bundle in static files 404

Tags: python, django

I'm having an issue with serving my static files that are placed in the static folder with webpack. It does not give me a traceback or error, just a 404 that the file doesn't exist.

My settings.py

```
DEBUG = True
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
# This is /Users/ml/Documents/Python/MyProject/site/static
STATIC_ROOT = str(ROOT_DIR('static'))
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # This is /Users/ml/Documents/Python/MyProject/site/apps/static
    str(APPS_DIR.path('static')),
)
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
```

My urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    # URL config here...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

My folder structure

```
.
project/
templates/
static/dist/main.j346h346hkjh346.css
manage.py
webpack.config.js
```

I try to visit `/static/dist/main.j346h346hkjh346.css` and I get a 404 error. It fails to serve. What am I missing?

Comment: Django won't serve the static with debug set to false.

Comment: @The_Cthulhu_Kid Sorry I copied that line from my prod file. Actually it is set to True but not working.

Comment: What is the full exception?

Comment: what is ROOT_DIR? seems to be function according to `ROOT_DIR('static')`, can you post its code?

Comment: Try `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, 'static'))`

Comment: @The_Cthulhu_Kid I don't get an exception, it's just a 404.

Comment: But if you are running on debug you should get the full stacktrace. Are you using `runserver`? If not, try running `collectstatic`

Comment: I was able to find the issue. The actual issue had to do with how I output some of the static files that was missing with Webpack. I added that additional information to the question and answer. If someone have something to add it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after additional testing I found the issue.

The issue was that I was using Webpack to bundle my static files and I output them straight to the `/static/` folder. When I instead output them to a separate folder (`./assets/dist/`) and then added the `./assets/` folder to my `STATICFILES_DIRS`,  I was able to locate my files.

I was suprised by this, I didn't think that the `/static/` folder only could be used by `collectstatic`, and that each file had to have a second source as well. Maybe someone else can add some comments about why this is.